# Table 'tbl_name' is specified twice, both as a target for 'UPDATE' and as a separate source for data

Tags: mysql, sql

I am facing issue during the execution of the following query

```
UPDATE tbluser_payment
SET payment_date = SUBSTRING(payment_date, 1, 2) + 1
WHERE
    trans_updatetime IN (
        SELECT
            trans_updatetime
        FROM
            `tbluser_payment`
        WHERE
            DAY (
                cast(trans_updatetime AS date)
            ) IN ('28', '29', '30', '31')
    )
```

I searched through many questions but get nothing to related with this query
they were inserting record into the database .

I want to update `payment_date` coloumn with 1 if where clause return true

Is this is possible through this way ?

Any Help Will be Appreciated

Thanks!

Comment: Show us the table definition and some sample data.

Comment: `SUBSTRING` is returning a string (text), what do you expect when you do `+1` with a text? From your comments I take, that this is kind of a string-formatted date value. This is something one should not do... Try to cast your `payment_date` to a proper date format and do the maths against the proper type. If you cannot change this (and you really should!) you might convert it back to a string in your needed format....

Answer (score 3):

I don't think a sub-query is needed here. Use the condition in the where clause.

```
UPDATE tbluser_payment
SET payment_date = SUBSTRING(payment_date, 1, 2) + 1
WHERE DAY(cast(trans_updatetime AS date)) IN ('28', '29', '30', '31')
```

Edit: Use `if` to set the payment_date column in mmyyyy format.

```
UPDATE tbluser_payment
SET payment_date = IF(length(SUBSTRING(payment_date, 1, 2) + 1) < 2,
                      '0' + SUBSTRING(payment_date, 1, 2) + 1, 
                       SUBSTRING(payment_date, 1, 2) + 1
                     ) 
                     + SUBSTRING(payment_date, 3)
WHERE DAY(cast(trans_updatetime AS date)) IN ('28', '29', '30', '31')
and SUBSTRING(payment_date, 1, 2) <> 12
```

Comment: i have reuslt in payment date like '022016' and i want to make it 032016

the current query give 3

Comment: data comes in this form   '022016'

I want to change this starting 02 with 03 if where clause become true

Comment: which dbms is being used?

Comment: @UmairKhan . . . This answers your question -- it is using the same date logic as your question and fixes the problem you mention.  You should probably ask another question, if this doesn't do exactly what you need.

Comment: and when the payment date is '122016', this will set it to '132016'. (I expect the next question should be "How do I add one month to a date value stored as a string".)